# Ember 1.10+grunt+EAK: "Could not find <template_name> template or view" after migration from 1.9.1

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Ember App Kit with `grunt` and I'm trying to switch to Ember 1.10 and can't get HTMLBars working :/

#### TL;DR

After migration, I've got my HTMLBars templates lodaded in `Ember.TEMPLATES` but they're not visible either by Ember nor in `App.__container.lookup.cache`.

#### Details

The steps I did:

- updated ember and ember-data
- updated `package.json` (`"grunt-ember-templates": "0.5.0"`)
- updated my `Gruntfile.js` (`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates')` added a task `emberTemplates`)
- passed the options to `emberTemplates`:

  ```
  {
    debug: [],
    options: {
      templateCompilerPath: 'vendor/ember/ember-template-compiler.js',
      handlebarsPath: 'vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js',
      templateNamespace: 'HTMLBars'
    },
    'public/assets/templates.js': [
      'app/templates/**/*.hbs'
    ],
  };
  ```
- removed `handlebars.js` from `index.html` and replaced `ember.js` with `ember.debug.js`

Now, I've got my `public/assets/templates.js` file generated in a proper way, I had several compilation errors coming from `ember-template-compiler`, so this part, I assume, is working fine.

Lastly, in the app, I can see all my templates loaded in `Ember.TEMPLATES` variable but unfortunately, they're not accessible from `App.__container__.lookup.cache` or `App.__container__.lookup('template:<template_name>')`.

The way I'm trying to render the template that throws an error is (and it's working with Ember 1.9):

```
export default AuthRoute.extend({

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();
    this.render('user-details', {
      into: 'base',
      outlet: 'profile',
      controller: 'user-details'
    });
  }
});
```

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Bonus question: what is `debug` field in `emberTemplates`  configuration? If I don't define it, it raises an error (`Required config property "emberTemplates.debug" missing.`) while compiling. Could that be a possible reason?

Bonus question 2: where should `templates.js` file go? The intuition tells me `/tmp` but then, even `Ember.TEMPLATES` is an empty object...

EDIT [**SOLUTION**]:

I missed `templateBasePath: "app/templates"` line in the `emberTemplates` options. Because of that, `Ember.TEMPLATES` object was sth similar to this:

```
{
  "app/templates/base.hbs": {},
  "app/templates/components/component.hbs": {}
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  "base.hbs": {},
  "components/component.hbs": {}
}
```

which is the format that Ember resolver (`ember-application/system/resolver`) in the `resolveTemplate` method expects.

Comment: any ideas? anyone? even stupid ones? :)

Comment: One struggles to find the right metaphor. Steaming pile? House of cards? Bowl of spaghetti? Whichever it is, things should not be this hard, meaning this is not a well-designed framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: using `grunt-ember-templates` and this Gruntfile task, I got it working:

```
emberTemplates: {
    options: {
        precompile: true,
        templateBasePath: "templates",
        handlebarsPath: "node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js",
        templateCompilerPath: "bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js"
    },
    "dist/js/templates.js": ["templates/**/*.hbs"]
}
```

Differences seem to be `precompile: true` and point the `handlebarsPath` to the dependency in `node_modules`. Also the `templateBasePath` makes the ids like `application` instead of `templates/application`. Or in your case `app/templates/application`.

To answer your Bonus question 2, put templates.js after you load ember.js but before your app.js. Mine script includes look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/ember/ember.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/templates.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

====================================

EDIT: Ignore this newbness...

It seems like the `grunt-ember-templates` task is outdated, or its dependencies are outdated. Remove it. I was able to hack together this solution:

Use `grunt-contrib-concat` instead. The money is with the `process` option.

```
    concat: {
        dist: {
            // other concat tasks...
        },
        templates: {
            options: {
                banner: '',
                process: function(src, filepath) {
                    var name = filepath.replace('app/templates/','').replace('.hbs','');
                    var Map = {
                        10: "n",
                        13: "r",
                        39: "'",
                        34: '"',
                        92: "\\"
                    };
                    src = '"' + src.replace(/[\n\r\"\\]/g, function(m) {
                        return "\\" + Map[m.charCodeAt(0)]
                    }) + '"';                       

                    return 'Ember.TEMPLATES["'+name+'"] = Ember.HTMLBars.template(Ember.HTMLBars.compile('+src+'));\n';
                }
            },
            files: {
                'public/assets/templates.js': 'app/templates/**/*.hbs'
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hey @Jamie, thanks for your answer. I don't have any problems compiling the handlebars, I do have `templates.js` generated correctly. I even have the HTMLBars templates visible in my app under `Ember.TEMPLATES`. The only problem is they're not visible by Ember's engine while rendering (e.g. `container.lookup('template:my-template')`)

Comment: And why do you say `grunt-ember-templates` is deprecated? Here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html @rwjblue mentioned it as recommended one.

Comment: First off, I'm a total EmberJS newb. So my solution likely isn't the 'correct' one. I read the blog post more closely and then was lead to this post: https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates/pull/77 Probably some clues in the comments. I'll try using `grunt-ember-templates` again and get back to you once I figure it out. Sorry for the left-field solution!

Comment: That's fine, man! I really appreciate your help! I was just asking questions, trying to understand the problem. You're helping me, so it's purely positive behavior! :)

Comment: Okay, I got it working in my app using `grunt-ember-templates`. I've edited the answer to show you my grunt task, which doesn't apply directly to you (wrong paths, etc).

Comment: hey Jamie, sorry for my silence, I was out for a while... I tried your ideas and nothing worked :/ I'll take a closer look later this week and will describe the solution... or try to switch to ember-cli... anyway, I'm upvoting your answer because you put a lot of effort, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was going to get in touch. EmberCLI is the way to go. It's the future of building Ember apps! I abandoned my grunt file and use EmberCLI now for everything - it's so much easier. The latest version requires you make a few changes so that it uses the latest Ember (1.10) and latest Ember-Data. Let me know if you need help setting that up.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have problems with ember-cli itself, I'm using it in the other projects but this particular one has some customized build steps added and that'd be pretty painful to get it all working the same way with brocolli

Comment: Hey, I just missed `templateBasePath: "app/templates"` line! I figured it looking at `ember-application/system/resolver` in `resolveTemplate` method, that in `Ember.TEMPLATES` I had an object like `app/templates/base.hbs` instead of `base.hbs`. Thanks Jamie again!

Answer (score 0):

So the whole solution is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  debug: {
    src: "app/templates/**/*.{hbs,hjs,handlebars}",
    dest: "tmp/result/assets/templates.js"
  },
  dist: {
    src: "<%= emberTemplates.debug.src %>",
    dest: "<%= emberTemplates.debug.dest %>"
  },
  options: {
    templateCompilerPath: 'vendor/ember/ember-template-compiler.js',
    handlebarsPath: 'vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js',
    templateNamespace: 'HTMLBars',
    templateBasePath: "app/templates"
  }
};
```

where all my templates reside in `app/templates/` directory.

I'm still using:

```
<script src="/assets/templates.js"></script>
```

in `index.html`.

Maybe somebody will find it useful ;)